# Cannot get python IDLE 2.7, 3.3 to run - OS X

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am running a MacBook Pro with 8gb of memory and a 2.5GHz processor. I run OS X Mavericks, but this problem has happened on other operating systems as well. when I try to open the editor, or even open a python file, this happens:
[image: It crashes]

This has been a problem since I got into python. I have tried as many versions as I can, and the same screen pops up. Please help

Comment: How did you install IDLE?

Comment: I went to the python website, downloaded the python dmg, opened the folder and ran the enclosed file

Comment: _"I went to the python website, downloaded the python dmg, opened the folder and ran the enclosed file"_ you need to install it, I hope you didn't run it directly from the .dmg

Answer (score 3):

I recently also upgraded a friends iMac to OS X 10.9 Mavericks and her Python to 2.7.6. If you mount the `python-2.7.6-macosx10.6.dmg` disk image there's a text file named `ReadMe.txt`. If you ahem, actually read it, right near the beginning it says:

> ```
>            **** IMPORTANT ****
> ```
>
> ## Update your version of Tcl/Tk to use IDLE or other Tk applications
>
> To use IDLE or other programs that use the Tkinter graphical user
>   interface toolkit, you may need to install a newer third-party version
>   of the Tcl/Tk frameworks.  Visit
>   http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information
>   about supported and recommended versions of Tcl/Tk for this version of
>   Python and of Mac OS X.

Here's what http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk currently looks like (my highlighting):

[image: Screenshot show webpage with information on using IDLE on Mac OS X]

To summarize: You need to download and install **ActiveTcl 8.5.15.1** (which is mislabeled ActiveTcl 8.5.15.0) from [ActiveState's webpage](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads). After doing that you should be able to run IDLE:

[image: Screenshot showing Python 2.7.6 Shell IDLE window running on OS X Mavericks]

I haven't actually tried to do it yet, but from what I read it sounds like the same process applies to Python 3.3.3 and its IDLE app.

Comment: So after installing ActiveTcl 8.5.15.1 you get exactly the same results?

Comment: I can verify I'm having the exact same problem.  Installing the new version of ActiveTCL had no effect.

Comment: @Stephen: This information in this 2+ year old answer has become outdated. The latest information at the first link now says to install ActiveTcl 8.5.17.0. Beyond that I can't help...my friend with the iMac died and I no longer have access to one.

Comment: Hi -- Thanks for the response.  I ended up installing it via MacPorts after I found a thread suggesting I use it to install "python34-tkinter" (along with "python34", aka Python 3.4).  Worked great, and I now have Python 3.4 and 2.7, each with working IDLEs.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem.

I was finally able to install Python (and IDLE) via MacPorts by also installing a package called "pyXX-tkinter" -- where XX is the version, e.g. py34-tkinter for Python 3.4.